# how to use await or async in jvm kotlin?

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, async-await, coroutine

I'm trying to write an example in kotlin await/async functions, which should work just the same as a c# await example. It works without errors, but I'm not sure whether I understand both of them correctly, and maybe I create too many async-coroutines. Can anyone give me some suggestion about this? thanks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-make-multiple-web-requests-in-parallel-by-using-async-and-await

```
package diki.test

import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.runBlocking
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils

fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    startButton_Click().await();
    println("time=" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
}

fun startButton_Click() = async {
    CreateMultipleTasksAsync().await()
}

fun CreateMultipleTasksAsync() = async {
    val d1 = ProcessURLAsync("http://a")
    val d2 = ProcessURLAsync("http://a1")
    val d3 = ProcessURLAsync("http://a111")
    val d1r = d1.await()
    val d2r = d2.await()
    val d3r = d3.await()
}

fun ProcessURLAsync(url: String) = async {
    Thread.sleep(RandomUtils.nextLong(500, 1000))//mock network job
    url.length
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Thread.sleep()` use the `delay` coroutine. Also have a look at `awaitAll()`

Comment: Checkout official docs: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html#structured-concurrency-with-async

Answer (score 1):

`async/await` for `CreateMultipleTasksAsync` and `startButton_Click` is useless.
Just make  them `suspend` functions.

And +1 for `delay` instead of `Thread.sleep`